# Can PHP crash and expose source code?

Tags: php, nginx

I am running NGINX and PHP fast CGI. I have a simple PHP website witch has some credentials hardcoded inside the source code.

Will nginx serve the actual source code of the website instead of the interpreted version should the php-fpm process crash?

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: Most likely not due to a crash but due to misconfiguration - ie. your web server serves the file as-is instead of passing it to PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, yes. Though far more likely, as others have noted, is a misconfiguration, causing requests to not be sent to the interpreter and revealing source code.

A common mitigation to this is moving sensitive files, like a configuration file containing database credentials, to outside of document root. MVC frameworks encourage this by using a front controller. That is, the only source code exposed to document root is a tiny `index.php` file. The rest of the source code is read from outside of document root. This minimizes the impact of the interpreter being misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly common issue is printing stack traces, either through a custom error handler or `display_errors = on` in php.ini, and [revealing database credentials when the connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6455018/120999).

There are also Nginx/PHP misconfigurations that will result in serving your files as plaintext rather than passing them through the interpreter, but those are more likely to be caught as you test your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP FPM is not configured to execute `.php` files (or not configured correctly), in some cases `nginx -t` does not complain, but you get a fly-by php source code download if opening the page. If you make modifications to this particular section in your `server` block, always make sure that the page renders as it should.

If PHP crashes, you will always get an `HTTP 502 Bad Gateway` error on Nginx and all this should not happen.